# Saving Certain Area Of Canvas File With Larger Resolution C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, canvas, png

This is my current application GUI, its still not been finalized as I am just trying to get the main functions to work (This is for self practice),

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gtsz5k4mtpkuva5/appLatest.png?dl=0

At first when I was trying to save the image it was saving the whole canvas (printCanvas) then I learnt it was possible to "crop" the rendered image, but now my image is 480 x 480.

I am just wondering, how would I know increase the resolution of the image, I would like to to be able to be printed on something like A3?

Here is my current code, for the Rendering / Cropping of the image,

```
 private static void SaveUsingEncoder(FrameworkElement visual, string fileName, BitmapEncoder encoder)
        {
            var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)visual.ActualWidth, (int)visual.ActualHeight, 92, 92, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            renderTargetBitmap.Render(visual);

            var crop = new CroppedBitmap(renderTargetBitmap, new Int32Rect(610, 130, 480, 480));


            var bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap);
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(crop));

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                encoder.Save(fileStream);
            }
        }
```

Thanks for any insight you can provide!

Comment: did you try changing `RenderTargetBitmap` dpi from 92 to something larger like 300 or 600?

Comment: @dkozl You mean,  var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)visual.ActualWidth, (int)visual.ActualHeight, 92, 92, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);..Yeah I changed the Int Values, but then the saved image was just a black screen? When I put it back to 92, 92 it saves the image normally

Comment: Does anyone else have any idea please Im really stuck here :(